# Is praying Salatul janazah obligatory?

Tags: funeral

In my mosque, almost every Friday there is salatul janazah. Sometimes there is a very important thing I have to do and so I have to leave and not pray. Is it haram to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Funeral prayers are a communal obligation (Fard-e-Kifayah), i.e. if some from among the community do it, the obligation is fulfilled from the whole community, but if none participate then all are blameworthy([source](https://islamqa.info/en/14040)).